# How to optimize for a 50million+ row table read with SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, optimization, select, python

I have a large table (32 GB) with about 52 million rows. The table structure involves a few numerical and a few string columns, out which I select only one varchar column. I don't need the rest.

This varchar column is actually JSON data, which I insert into MongoDB using my custom made python decoder.

The problem I'm having at the moment is that my workstation has 16 GB of memory and I don't want to just run the python decoder on the entire 32 GB table. Whenever I try to find the size of the result set using the query below, it crashes midway with the error `2013: Lost Connection to MySQL server`

```
select sum(row_size) 
from (
  select 
    char_length(json_data)
  as row_size 
  from raw_data
) as table1;
```

How do I process it slowly, or what's the best way to read a large table like this in small digestible chunks?

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that the column that I need (the json data column), is not an index. I don't know if making it an index would actually be a good idea, since it's a large field with a large string containing the JSON data

Comment: You might take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49685/mysql-linux-client-timeout-keepalive to see if you can avoid disconnections this way. Your query looks ok to me, it will take long, because there's a lot of data to process, no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reasonable way for you is to create stored procedure with `CURSOR` that should scan the table row by row and calculate desired value. Otherwise you'll stuck with really HUGE on-disk temporary table without indexing that cause timeouts and disconnections just like you already have.

Comment: If you look at the [execution plan on MySQL 5.7.12](http://rextester.com/VNZ32713), it doesn't look like it's actually creating a temporary table, it's just a sequential full table scan. I can't tell about other versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Cursors won't help.  Temp table is not needed.  Indexing `json_data` is not useful, and may not be possible.

It should not take "too" long to do the following, even in your hardware configuration:

```
         SELECT  SUM(char_length(json_data))
            FROM  raw_data
```

Try it.

Comment: I think you're way more right than the accepted answer. However reading 32gb from disk may very well time out Network too, so @joanolo's comment completes this answer nicely.